# Rewriting Parameters to Subfolder Structure (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I am looking to rewrite 2 parameters to form a cleaner structure:

```
CURRENT: ?fruit=Oranges&vegetable=Carrots

DESIRED: /oranges-vs-carrots/
```

Any comments or explanation on the regex would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?fruit=([^&]+)&vegitable=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-vs-%2? [NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /?fruit=$1&vegitable=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-vs-([a-z]+)/$ ?fruit=$1&vegetable=$2
```

site for testing it: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/